# Registry Startup not working windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-installer, registry

I created windows application ,I want to start my application on windows startup
for that i written following code in installer class. but when i am checking registry using regedit i didnt get registry value. and my application not working.

```
        public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Commit(savedState);


            try
            {
                RegistryKey add = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                add.SetValue("ToposcreenServer", "\"" + Application.ExecutablePath.ToString() + "\"");


                RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{70E25B31-99A9-474C-8990-CE28FBCEAAD1}", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default);
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.SetValue("SystemComponent", 1, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
                    key.Close();
                }
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));
                Process.Start(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\ToposcreenServer.exe");
                GLobalclass.WriteLog("Installer Executed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                GLobalclass.WriteLog("Installer Error :" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code sets two registry values. Are both of them not set?

Comment: When this code runs, what is written to the log ('executed' or 'error')?

Answer (score 2):

If this is an Everyone install then that code won't write to HKCU of the installing user because the code is running with the System account credentials, not the installing user's.

Anyway, you don't need code to set the Run key. Go to the registry view in the IDE and add registry folders to get to that Run key in HKCU. Then add an item with the Nama ToposcreenSaver and the value [TARGETDIR]my.exe assuming your executable is in the Application Folder in the File System view. It's possible that it won't run anyway if it requires elevation on a UAC system.

(If this code is really in an installer class, it's also not clear why you're using Application and ExecuteablePath because an installer class is a Dll being called from an msiexec.exe process, and is nothing at all to do with whatever executable you want to run. Surely it's the name of an executable you are installing?)

You don't need to set SystemComponent in the registry key. That registry key may not be there at the time your custom action runs, and what you should really do is open your MSI file with Orca and add ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT to the Property table, give it a value of 1.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367750(v=vs.85).aspx

If the app really is a conventional screensave this might be the best way to do it:

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-install-screensaver.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that `add` is not null, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xthy8s8d(v=vs.110).aspx .